# Dynamic Forms Authentication Timeout?

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

I am using ASP.NET Forms Authentication and currently setting the timeout value in Web.config. Is there a way to set this timeout from code instead? I would like to have different timeouts for different users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the `FormsAuthenticationTicket` on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa480476.aspx)

```
FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1,
        "userName",
        DateTime.Now,
        your_time_out_goes_here, // value of time out property
        false, // Value of IsPersistent property
        String.Empty,
        FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
```